# down in/with the elevator

Tags: grammar, word-choice, idiomatic-language

> I've just sent a cake down in/with the elevator, so I hope they're hungry downstairs.

Is "in" or "with" correct here?

Is the sentence natural?

Comment: This sentence sounds like you just put the cake on the floor of an empty elevator and hoped that someone on the floor below notices it. Usually you'd mention the person who's actually carrying the cake.

Comment: That is actually what I mean. Just the cake, no person.

Comment: Did you place the cake on the floor of a passenger elevator and send it down?  Is this a passenger elevator or is it a service elevator that is just used for small items?

Comment: "IN the elevator."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence isn't natural, because you don't send things using an elevator that way. Elevators transport people, and even freight elevators have room for people to stand in them, and people move the freight around.

You could say:

*I've just sent down a cake, so I hope they're hungry downstairs.*

Here, you're omitting whom you've sent and where exactly they're going. *Downstairs* can mean down one story, or at any story below the current one.

You could also say:

*I've just sent Julieanne down with a cake, so I hope they're hungry downstairs.*

If you needed to specify the elevator (as opposed to the pole or the stairs I guess), you could say:

*I've just sent Julieanne down in the elevator with a cake, so I hope they're hungry downstairs.*

Of course, I am assuming you really mean a normal *elevator* and not *[dumbwaiter](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dumbwaiter)*. A dumbwaiter is something you can put a cake in, and just send it. It's much smaller and it doesn't move people. It's also often manual.

> dumb·wait·er  (dŭmwā′tər)
> n.
>
> 1. A small elevator used to convey food or other goods from one floor of a building to another.
> 2. A portable serving stand or table.

If you do mean dumbwaiter, then you can say:

*I've just sent down a cake in the dumbwaiter, so I hope they're hungry downstairs.*

Again, though, you wouldn't need to mention the dumbwaiter unless there were multiple ways of sending the cake downstairs.